# Can other Antivirus solutions be used with Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, anti-virus

There is built-in AV software in Windows 8, will it will turn itself off when I install antivirus from another vendor?

Should I install another AV, or will default one suffice?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a subjective enough question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Default one will suffice for many people, but if you so desire, Windows Defender will step aside if you install a new AV solution.

**CAVEAT** Action Center has to recognize that it is installed, otherwise you will have to disable the Defender service manually.

Answer (score 0):

Well in my opinion 2 would be nice. But there is always the chance that some AVs will conflict with each other. I remember McAfee doing the same for me.

So yes another one should do but just 2 or else it would consume a lot of your resources.

Comment: I would suggest against 2. One should be enough. :)

Comment: But you have a greater chance of defending yourself against viruses in case one doesn't catch it if since it isn't in their virus definition database.

Comment: +1. For the casual user, one is probably enough. But two provides better protection. Besides everything ultimately boils down to how much your computer interacts with the outside world (Internet, pendrive, etc). If not at all, antivirus is not necessary at all. If average, Windows Defender should be enough.

Comment: I think most antivirus programs work the same way. If it gets by one, it will most likely get by both. You're just wasting your time and resources with two. (note: this is just my opinion and suggestion). :)

Comment: Having two anti-virus security software suites installed at the same time is bad idea.  It can cause your system to crash.  Having 2 WILL NOT increase the chances of you detecting something.

Comment: As long as both don't have real-time scanning enabled, it will be fine, otherwise what Ramhound said. You can have one for real-time scanning and use the other for on-demand scans.

Answer (score 0):

The default antivirus should be enough. I used Microsoft's Security Essentials in Windows 7 and it worked great. If you have a specific need for another program that should work as well.

Answer (score 0):

As others have suggested installing a second anti-virus, let me say ***NO!***

That will just introduce conflicts and false positives and prevent either from being fully functional.

The default Windows 8 anti-virus is Windows Defender, which evolved from Microsoft Security Essentials which has been my choice for years now.  It has been comparable to Norton and McAfee in terms of protection, if not better.  Personally I like it more because its just seamless, and it doesn't slow down my system the way Norton always did.

So you shouldn't need anything else.

Comment: What conflicts? See Jared's answer.

Comment: I wasn't aware that Windows Defender will do this, but as a general rule other anti-virus software will not.

Comment: "as a general rule other anti-virus software will not" - True, this holds true only for Defender. Also, you might want to edit your answer slightly to replace MSE with Defender (although the latter includes many features from the former, it is not officially MSE any longer).

Comment: Ah, I thought it still still officially MSSE, just integrated.  I shall correct it.