# Do I need Avast! if I have Windows Defender?

Tags: windows-8, anti-virus, avast

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does Windows 8 require any sort of Virus protection?](https://superuser.com/questions/494074/does-windows-8-require-any-sort-of-virus-protection)

I haven't got my head completely around Windows Defender for Windows 8. What is it? I have Avast! but it seems like they are warning for the same things. Are the programs like each other? What are the benefits of each programs?

Lastly, do I need Avast! in Windows 8? Or can I rely on Windows Defender alone?

Comment: Keep in mind that most AV software borders on scareware most of the time anyway and is snake oil at best. Common sense, having a limited user account, backups and patched software help most of the time. And there's little that protects you against a 0day (I saw only one so far, and that was on a system with a well-known AV product which did nothing).

Comment: @Joey - I have caught many files over the years that having some sort of protection pays off.

Comment: I have MSE running (XP). I also use malwarebytes for an added layer. It has flagged ones that MSE missed, though not for some time. I recommend it.

Comment: See also: [Can other Antivirus solutions be used with Windows 8?](http://superuser.com/questions/495813/can-other-antivirus-solutions-be-used-with-windows-8)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Windows Defender in Windows 8 is essentially an improved version of Microsoft Security Essentials. It provides both anti-virus and anti-spyware capabilities and works alongside the Windows Firewall to protect your computer. Granted, you might want Avast if you are familiar with its AV capabilities and prefer its features to those of Windows Defender, but out of the box; Windows 8 is secure without the need for extra security software.

Answer (score 2):

As a note, you should never install more than one antivirus; having more than one is likely to make your system slow, unstable, and will likely cause false positives.

Therefore, unless there is some spefici aspect of Windows Defender (which has received good reviews, in general) you dislike, I'd recommend sticking with it and not installing avast.

If you do choose Avast, remember to disable Windows Defender first!

Comment: Thank you. I have already installed Avast but maybe it is time to uninstall.

Comment: What this refers to is having 2 AVs running at the same time, and it is true that you should only have one RUNNING. I think a second one, run only on command is also important.

Comment: More than likely Avast disabled defender during the install routine.